# Detect Browser or tab close - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, dom-events

I have a Angular 8 web application where an API is called whenever the browser is closed or the browser tab is closed where my application is running. I have tried the following code

```
    @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
     @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ["$event"]) unload(event) {
        //calling api
     }
    }
```

The logic for the api (data in variables and functions) runs as expected, but only when i resize the browser window (inspect element) or add any breakpoint.
I also tried https://v8.angular.io/api/core/Directive#host property.
Am i adding the listener to the wrong component or the DOM object or listener is getting removed or not getting added.

Answer (score 8):

The unload event can complete and window close before the call is made.

See this article to run async calls in ngOnDestroy and ensure ngOnDestroy is called on window close events (especially hot tip #1 and #2 sections).

It details how to complete a service call on the window unload event.
[Wesley Grimes Angular ngOnDestroy upgrades](https://wesleygrimes.com/angular/2019/03/29/making-upgrades-to-angular-ngondestroy.html)

**Here is how I use it in app.component which adds a record to the database when I close the browser window:**

Note - some imports may not be relevant, just copying code from my app as it is.

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener, OnDestroy  } from '@angular/core';
```

...

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
```

...

```
 @HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  async ngOnDestroy()
  {
    await this.myService.AddItem().subscribe();
  }
```

**my-service.ts:**

```
 AddItem(): Observable<any>
 {
  return this.http.get<any>(environment.apiURL + 'items/AddItem', httpOptions);
 }
```

Comment: I tried both the techniques of using ngOnDestroy didn't workout.

Comment: Works for me. I've edited my answer to show the relevant code I use,

Comment: Works each time on mine. Have you got implements OnDestroy on your class declaration? Also if you add the code to another component within app component does a breakpoint in ngOnDestroy get hit when that component is destroyed? E.g by navigating off the component? Have you also checked network tab in developed tools to see if service call is being made?

Comment: Also have to got async on your ngOnDestroy declaration and await on the service call within it?

Comment: Yes. I just ran my application with your changes it is working bt only on Firefox, Chrome and Edge the hostlistener code is not getting execute. I ran the same project on other machines same problem.

Comment: ```@HostListener('window:beforeunload')   async ngOnDestroy() {...}``` this works partly well. However, this call is triggered even when the user moves away from the browser to some other application like word and Excel and comes back to the browser tab. How do I trigger this call ONLY when the browser tab or window is closed?